# ¿Por qué no se centra el div? CSS

Tags: html, css, div

Quiero que el div container se me centre tanto vertical como horizontalmente.
CSS.

**¿Alguna explicación de por qué lo centra horizontalmente y no verticalmente?**

**Código HTML:**

```css
::-moz-selection {
  background: #b3d4fc;
  text-shadow: none;
}

 ::selection {
  background: #b3d4fc;
  text-shadow: none;
}

html {
  padding: 30px 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  color: #737373;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

html,
input {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

body {
  max-width: 700px;
  border: 1px solid #b3b3b3;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 10px #a7a7a7, inset 0 1px 0 #fff;
  background: #fcfcfc;
}

h2 {
  color: #D35780;
  margin: 0 10px;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 span {
  color: #bbb;
  font-size: 80px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}

input::-moz-focus-inner {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Error 404</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos_error404.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>
      <span>Error 404</span><br/> Page not found<br/> Página no encontrada
    </h2>
    <br/>
    <img id="imagen" src="imagenes/casa_rural.png" alt="Osmarrural" />
    <br/>
    <p>¡Vaya! Algo salió mal.</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Imagen: se me forma un scroll cuando el contenido es menor... no se me centra.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: `<center>` es una etiqueta desaprobada hace ya mucho tiempo, y por el `doctype` veo que usas HTML5 así que no deberías usar esa etiqueta sino las propiedades CSS equivalentes. Por otra parte `<center>` solo centra en horizontal

Comment: ¿Cuál sería el equivalente a <center> en CSS? Para centrar el contenido en el div.

Comment: Hay varias opciones, `margin: auto` o `text-align:center` generalmente o con `transform` y posición absoluta también se puede conseguir. Eso para centrar en horizontal que es lo que hace `<center>`, en vertical es más coplicado pero hay varias maneras de conseguirlo también

Comment: Etiqueta <center> eliminada de mi código. Muchas gracias por la aportación.

Comment: Te recomiendo que hagas una búsqueda en el sitio (p.e. Centrar verticalmente) porque ya existen varias preguntas similares a ésta y con respuestas que te van a servir igualmente.

Comment: @omaza1990, si no quieres que muestre el Scroll, puedes usar en el body el atributo **overflow** y esconderlo, algo así: `body{ overflow:hidden;}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Una de las opciones es usar la propiedad de **CSS** `display:flex` y con ella las propiedades `align-items: center` `justify-content: center;` que centran cualquier elemento que este dentro del contrenedor (todos los hijos).

```css
*{
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
  div{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background: rgb(75, 167, 170);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
```

```html
<div class="">
      <h1>H1 CENTRADO</h1>
      <h2>Segundo elemento Centrado</h2>
    </div>
```

Otra opción cuando queremos que un solo elemento este centrado para ello agregamos al elemento hijo en este caso el `h1` la propiedad `position:absolute` y le agregamos un left de `50%` y un top de `50%` que para centrarlo exactamente en el centro le agregamos la propiedad `transform: translate(-50%,-50%)`

```css
*{
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
  div{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background: rgb(75, 167, 170)
  }
  
  div h1 {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  }
```

```html
<div class="">
      <h1>H1 CENTRADO</h1>
    </div>
```

**Ejemplo funcional**

```css
::-moz-selection {
  background: #b3d4fc;
  text-shadow: none;
}

::selection {
  background: #b3d4fc;
  text-shadow: none;
}

html {
  color: #737373;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  height: 100%;
}

html,
input {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

body {
 
  border: 1px solid #b3b3b3;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  
  background: #fcfcfc;
  height: calc(100% - 2px);/*quitar el scroll al agregar borde se agrega un pixel mas por cada lado del body con calc(alto -2px) le quitamos los pixeles agregados */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

h2 {
  color: #D35780;
  margin: 0 10px;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 span {
  color: #bbb;
  font-size: 80px;
}

.container {
  padding:15px;
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
  display:block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 10px #a7a7a7, inset 0 1px 0 #fff;
  display:flex;/*centar elementos hijo h2,p,casa */
  justify-content:center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

p input::-moz-focus-inner {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>Error 404</h2>
  
  <img src="https://image.freepik.com/iconos-gratis/casa_318-64534.jpg" alt="Osmarrural" width="50" height="50" />

  <p>¡Vaya! Algo salió mal.</p>
</div>
```

Espero les ayude saludos.

> Ejemplo con la ayuda de [blonfu](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/7176/blonfu)

Comment: Mi problema es que no se centra verticalmente, horizontalmente y el contenido dentro del <div> sí, pero verticalmente no. Como que me coge más altura de la deseada... Edito mi código actual en la pregunta.

Comment: amigo para obtener la altura del browser usa `height: 100vh` no se si es lo que necesitas pero si quieres una caja perfectamente cuadrada y que se acomode a la ventana tendría que ser con **javascript** pero eso si es algo mas complejo porque obtenemos el alto y en base a eso el ancho y despues acomodariamos los hijos.

Comment: No quiero que sea perfectamente cuadrada, quiero que con las dimensiones que tenga (x dimensiones) se centre en la pantalla. Totalmente centrada. (sin aplicar "de forma sucia" la propiedad margin-top).

Comment: Listo amigo ya tiene las dimensiones automáticas y se centra con `display:flex;` para la prueba agranda el ejemplo y pon mas pequeña la pantalla en ancho y en alto

Comment: Pues en mi programa no funciona el display:flex; no sé a qué se debe.

Comment: Abre un chat para ver si podemos conseguirlo, si tienes tiempo, claro está...

Comment: estas usando un navegador nuevo? revisa a ver y tienes que ponerle un padre que contiene el div a centrar y hay si funciona.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70518/discussion-between-omaza1990-and-luis-daniel-rovira-contreras).

Answer (score 3):

Lo más fácil sin duda es usando flexbox.

Simplifico un poco tu ejemplo para que se vea mejor, visto a pantalla completa se aprecia mejor que el `div` container esta centrado verticalmente:

```css
::-moz-selection {
  background: #b3d4fc;
  text-shadow: none;
}

::selection {
  background: #b3d4fc;
  text-shadow: none;
}

html {
  color: #737373;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  height: 100%;
}

html,
input {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

body {
  max-width: 700px;
  border: 1px solid #b3b3b3;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 10px #a7a7a7, inset 0 1px 0 #fff;
  background: #fcfcfc;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

h2 {
  color: #D35780;
  margin: 0 10px;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 span {
  color: #bbb;
  font-size: 80px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid 1px red;
}

p input::-moz-focus-inner {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>Error 404</h2>
  
  <img src="https://image.freepik.com/iconos-gratis/casa_318-64534.jpg" alt="Osmarrural" width="50" height="50" />

  <p>¡Vaya! Algo salió mal.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: El problema le tengo en el height: 100%; del HTML, debido a que si pongo 100% es innecesario debido a que quiero que el cuadro sea "cuadrado" y mida el alto del tamaño de pantalla completa, no quiero que el recuadro del div sea tan alargado y se transforme en un scroll. Mira mi imagen.

Comment: @omaza1990 Si pones 100% tienes scroll porque tambien tienes margenes y rellenos que se suman al `body`, tienes que tener eso en cuenta. Si quieres que sea un cuadrado no deberías usar el `body` para eso, sino crear un `div` con los estilos del recuadro y darle el tamaño que necesitas, coo ha hecho @LuisDanielRoviraContreras en su ejemplo

Comment: Por eso, tengo un <div> llamado "container" dentro del <body>

Comment: pero los estilos de la sombra, borde redondeado, etc. se los has puesto al `body`

Answer (score 2):

> "¿Alguna explicación de por qué lo centra horizontalmente y no
>   verticalmente?"

No se centra verticalmente porque el body, no ocupa el 100% del alto del navegador, en tu caso la altura depende del contenido que le estas agregando y por defecto los elementos con modelo de "bloque" como el body, se apilan hacia arriba.

**Recomendaciones:**

No es obligatorio 100%, pero es una buena práctica agregar un div contenedor más, que englobe toda la página. Puedes llamarlo "principal-container".

Deberías traspasar algunos de los estilos que le estás aplicando al html para el body, del body del div "principal-container" y algunos otros del body al "container".

Al html y body no colocarle muchos estilos de forma, sino de estructura, esto significa: Una **altura mínima del 100% del alto de la ventana** o min-height: 100vh; y su ancho al máximo de la ventana, lo cual no es necesario aplicarle ya que por defecto, los elementos de "bloque" tienen un width: 100%; También puedes 
incluir en este selector agrupado al "contenedor principal" y te servirá más adelante. Es decir, que quede así:

```
html, body, .principal-container {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Al body, si le puedes colocar algunos estilos de forma como base a todo el documento.

```
body { 
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Al contenedor principal le dejamos algunos estilos del body y será quien centrará todo lo demás (en teoría, se los puedes agregar al body y hará lo mismo, pero te recomiendo mejor hacerlo al contenedor principal), también te  recomiendo hacerlo con flexbox porque es más fácil y más cómodo así:

```
.principal-container {
  background: #f0f0f0; /*Lo pase del html a aquí*/
  color: #737373;
  padding: 30px 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /*centra horizontal los elementos "flex"*/
  align-items: center; /*Centra verticalmente los elementos "flex"*/
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Si te fijas al final puse un nuevo modelo de caja con el atributo, **box-sizing: border-box**, esto es para los padding que le apliquemos a este div, así como los bordes, no sumen a lo especificado en altura. Sin esta propiedad, la altura del contenedor principal sería: 100vh + 30px (padding-top) + 30px (padding-bottom) y queremos que solo tenga en cuenta los 100vh. De hecho puedes aplicar este atributo aquí o ponerselo por defecto a todos los elementos del html, con un hack medio famoso, usando el selector universal (*):

```
*{ box-sizing: border-box; }
```

Seguimos con el contenedor, a este le podemos aplicar la mayoría de los estilos que tenía el body y agregarle un width: 100%.

```
.container{
  width: 100%;
  background: #fcfcfc;
  max-width: 700px;
  border: 1px solid #b3b3b3;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 10px #a7a7a7, inset 0 1px 0 #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Verás que con esto todo estará centrado tanto vertical como horizontalmente. Con respecto a:

> "se me forma un scroll cuando el contenido es menor... no se me centra. "

Puedes evitar que surja la mayoria de las veces, si colocas el hack del selector universal.

Answer (score 1):

Tener un `div` verticalmente comenta lo siguiente `/* margin: 0 auto; */` en el `div` container [demostración](https://jsfiddle.net/72bzjn0j/).

```
.container {
    max-width: 400px;
    /* margin: 0 auto; */
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #b3b3b3;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 10px #a7a7a7, inset 0 1px 0 #fff;
    background: #fcfcfc;
}
```

> **Nota:** También le podrías añadir un `float: left;`

Para tener un `div` centrado vuelve añadir `margin: 0 auto;` [demostración](https://jsfiddle.net/72bzjn0j/1/).

```
.container {
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #b3b3b3;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 10px #a7a7a7, inset 0 1px 0 #fff;
    background: #fcfcfc;
}
```

[Otros ejemplos](https://jsfiddle.net/xsuct857/) usando `Flexbox` `table-cell`

> Se me forma un scroll cuando el contenido es menor.

Esto es inevitable debes pensar que una página web no solo sera visualizada desde un ordenador, si no en muchos dispositivos, y al querer ocultarlos con un `overflow:hidden;` el contenido se vera recortado.

Aun no entiendo porque deseas alinearlo de esas formas, en los casos responsive se ven mucho mejor cunado el contenido es centrado o se tiene un formato de espacio iguales tanto izquierda (`left`) y derecha (`right`).

Mi mejor recomendación es tener ya formatos responsive, adaptables para luego ya cualquier contendido que no se adapte irlos adaptando claro que no serán muchos estos casos, pero si se comienza sin algún formato adaptable sera un trabajo largo un gran dolor de cabeza.

**Ejemplo:**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  color: #222222;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: 'OpenSans', 'cursive', 'Releway', Roboto, Lato, Utsaah;
  background-color: #FBFBFB;
}

.container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.row {
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}

.container:before, .container:after, .row:before, .row:after {
  display: table;
  content: " ";
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 1170px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div> <span>http://www.blindtextgenerator.com/es</span> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Su código:**

```css
::-moz-selection {
  background: #b3d4fc;
  text-shadow: none;
}

 ::selection {
  background: #b3d4fc;
  text-shadow: none;
}

html {
  padding: 30px 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  color: #737373;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

html,
input {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

body {
  /*max-width: 700px;*/
  /*overflow:hidden;*/
}

h2 {
  color: #D35780;
  margin: 0 10px;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 span {
  color: #bbb;
  font-size: 80px;
}
/*
.container {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
*/
.container {
    max-width: 400px;
    /* margin: 0 auto; */
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #b3b3b3;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 10px #a7a7a7, inset 0 1px 0 #fff;
    background: #fcfcfc;
}

img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  
  width:120px;
  height:120px;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}

input::-moz-focus-inner {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Error 404</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos_error404.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>
      <span>Error 404</span><br/> Page not found<br/> Página no encontrada
    </h2>
    <br/>
    <img id="imagen" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/34/34707.svg" alt="Osmarrural" />
    <br/>
    <p>¡Vaya! Algo salió mal.</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Algunos artículos de interés, basado al tema:

- [No puedo centrar horizontalmente un <div> hijo de un <div> contenedor con flexbox](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/25072/no-puedo-centrar-horizontalmente-un-div-hijo-de-un-div-contenedor-con-flexbo)
- [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp)
- [librosweb](https://librosweb.es/libro/css/capitulo_12/centrar_una_pagina_verticalmente.html)
- [Otros](https://www.dariobf.com/centrar-verticalmente-con-css-6-formas-diferentes-de-lograrlo/)

Comment: Hola @omaza1990 es lo que deseas hacer?